# Crystal reports repeatable rows

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I have a crystal report in this form:

### group1

AER#

M1  A2  A3  A4  A5

M2  B2  B3  B4  B5

M2A  C2  C3  C4  C5

M3  D2  D3  D4  D5

M4  E2  E3  E4  E5

These records are grouped on the basis of group1 field.
I have a requirement that these records be displayed such that
for any same AER# value different M3 and M4 are displayed as:

### group1

AER#

M1  A2  A3  A4  A5

M2  B2  B3  B4  B5

M2A  C2  C3  C4  C5


M3  D2a  D3a  D4  D5

M4  E2b  E3a  E4  E5


M3  D2b  D3a  D4  D5

M4  E2b  E3b  E4  E5

Instead of two separate 5 line groups.
Meaning that for same AER# there could be 3 sets of rows with only last two rows different. They should be displayed in above fashion(with last two lines repeated three times) instead of 3 separate chunks.
Any suggestions?
Thanks. 
S

Answer (score 0):

```
Note: Currently I don't have Crystal Reports hence didn't got the chance to test below solution.
```

Extrace last two characters of the second column and group by those characters ater the grouping `AER#'

`Below is the example of the formula`

Assuming your column 2 name as `X`.

Create a formula `@group2`

```
x[2]+x[3]
```

Now use `@group2` to group and in group foooter place all the columns you require.